# Fancybox: call a function in parent from within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using Fancybox 2.

I am trying to find a way to information from the parent from within the iframe window. Here is my situation:

1. open Fancybox iframe from the parent
2. after the iframe is opened, user clicks on a button. This click needs info from the parent, for which I hope to call a function in the parent. **Please note that clicking on this button should not close the iframe.**

Is this something doable in Fancybox 2? I read many posts at SO and am unable to figure this out.

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in your parent page you have this function

```
function fnParent() {
    // returns some data 
};
```

... from within the iframed page you just need to call that function like :

```
parent.fnParent();
```

**Notice** that if you open fancybox in `iframe` mode, whatever interaction or `click` events inside the `iframe` will never close fancybox unless one clicked element calls the `parent.jQuery.fancybox.close()` method.

Also notice that the iframed page may need to have jQuery included and its own scripts and functions to process the response from the parent page.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1ncxan45/show)**